# URL Visible in UIActivityViewController

Tags: ios, uiactivityviewcontroller

I've seen this used in some apps and I can't seem to figure out how it's done - there seems to be nothing to set. When I set the url to share, it doesn't pop up automatically either, and I can't find any reference to it anywhere on the Internet which makes me feel like an idiot. Any possibilities? It's not urgent anyway I'm just curious. Thanks.

Screenshot of iOS Device with the UIActivityViewController visible with the URL bar:
http://twitter.com/SunburstEnzo/status/617736706402484224/photo/1

Edit: I can't believe I need 10 reputation to show you my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to do this. However, there's a third-party component named [JDSActivityVC](https://github.com/Jasdev/JDSActivityVC) which enables you to achieve this effect.

It's just a subclass of `UIActivityViewController` that adds a custom `UIView` with an `UILabel`.